# Click Once Deployment Error

Tags: deployment, clickonce

I am new to Click Once Application deployment so I think I may have a simple problem.  I have a window app that I created and deployed successfully as a ClickOnce App using Vis. Studio 2010 and deploying to a web service.  I made some changes to the app and changed the deployment location so I started the click Once Process over.  Now when I deploy I get an error.  The app builds fine, runs fine in VS 2010, when I deploy files are created.  Double clicking the App.application file will start the install of the app with a .Net framework error.

"Unhandled exception has occurred in your application.  If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue.  If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.

System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI is empty..."

I have double checked and triple checked the Publish Foldre Location and INstallation Folder URL to make sure they are pointing in the correct places and using the correct format.  I double and triple checked the Updates dialog box when you click the Updates button.  The combobox for the Application Updates matches the Installation Folder URL.  "\MyServer\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Transfer\Deploy\"  I double checked to make sure the required files are correct.  Security settings did not change.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you missed one backslash in your installation folder URL:

```
\\MyServer\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Transfer\Deploy\
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that if you are using some image/sound or log files then its Build Action must be "Content" type.